# Replace all CVS ident strings recursively in files within the GIT repository

Tags: php, git, recursion, replace, git-merge

How can I reach the goal to replace the following style CVS ident strings

```
<?php // $Id: index.php,v 1.123.5.56 2000/01/01 11:11:11 user Exp $
```

to

```
<?php // $Id$
```

recursively in all .php .class extension files within the GIT repository.

**My problem:**
I have two GIT repos having more thousand PHP files.

1. Repo one contains the original php code with unexpanded CVS
   idents.
2. Repo two contains the modified php code with expanded CVS idents + a lot modifications by me.

When I want to merge them, it gives conflicts at files having expanded CVS idents. However I want to ignore these changes, as I want to bother only with those real conflicts, which are happening between the original code & my modifications.

**Solutions I tried WITHOUT satisfactory result:**

- I tried a GIT solution with smudge & clean, but had no real success.
- I wrote a Perl script to replace (shrink) the CVS ident strings, but after it, I had a lot changes in the repo 2, which all needed to be solve the conflicts one by one.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Edited my original post, included my answers.

Comment: Why did you have a lot of changes after running the Perl script?

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you could use [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to find all the relevant files in the repository. Then copy the files to a backup file before doing the replacement:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;

File::Find::Rule->new
  ->file
  ->name(qr/\.(php|class)$/)
  ->exec( \&do_replacement )
  ->in('.');

sub do_replacement {
    my ( $fn, undef, $full_path ) = @_;

    $^I = '.bak';  # suffix of backup file
    local @ARGV = ( $fn );
    while (<>) {
        s{<\?php\s*//\s*\$Id:.*?\$}{<?php // \$Id\$}g;
        print;
    }
}
```